# C/C++ Messagebox from resource data

Tags: c++, c, string, resources

I am trying to read char pointer/string from resource, and then show it from messagebox. However it seems to be blank and I don't know if I am reading it correctly.

Here's my resources:

[image: Resources]

And here's the code that I am using to read it:

```
void main()
{
    HGLOBAL G1, G2;

    HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    G1 = LoadResource(hMod, FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(RT_RCDATA), "RESOURCE1"));
    G2 = LoadResource(hMod, FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(RT_RCDATA), "RESOURCE2"));

    //G1 = LoadResource(NULL, FindResource(NULL, "RCData", "RESOURCE1"));
    //G2 = LoadResource(NULL, FindResource(NULL, "RCData", "RESOURCE2"));

    MessageBoxA(NULL, (char*)LockResource(G1), (char*)LockResource(G1), MB_OK);
    MessageBoxA(NULL, (char*)LockResource(G2), (char*)LockResource(G2), MB_OK);


    /*char *strURL;
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL); 
    HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hModule, "RESOURCE1", "RCData"); //HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hModule, "RCData", "RESOURCE1"); 
    HGLOBAL hMemory = LoadResource(hModule, hResource);
    DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
    LPVOID lpAddress = LockResource(hMemory);

    memcpy(strURL, lpAddress, dwSize);

    MessageBoxA(0, strURL, strURL, MB_OK);*/

    ExitProcess(0);
    }
```

The commented parts are alternatives that I tried for reading it properly. What is going wrong? I know that the `RT_RCDATA` is not correct, because in the resources it's clearly `"RCDATA"` but then I also tried using just `LPCSTR` in quotes, but that didn't help either.

Also, I am not releasing the resource(FreeResource) because this is what MSDN says:

> This function is obsolete and is only supported for backward compatibility with 16-bit Windows. For 32-bit Windows applications, it is not necessary to free the resources loaded using LoadResource.

What is going wrong or what am I doing incorrectly?

*Edit: Bad tags because apparently I need some kind of reputation to add correct tags for this, makes absolutely no sense to me.*

Comment: MessageBox() displays a string.  So the sane thing to do is to use a string from a string table resource.  Hard to guess what you stuffed into that RCDATA resource.  Probably not a correctly encoded zero-terminated C string.  Skipping error checking is not correct either.

Comment: where to you have `MessageBox` API from? This isn't in the C library, nor in C++ I guess. Don't mix up the language in which you are writing with the tools that you are using.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I know the error checking isn't done properly but that is not the point. I also checked if the `G1` or `G2` are empty, and they are. But how do I get those strings(or char *) to a char pointer, so I can then use them for eg. displaying the messagebox? You can see from the image where the string(s) are stored, but does my code match with it? I believe no, but haven't figure out a way to do it correctly. A help or an example code would be appreciated. _Edit:_ Jens: `MessageBoxA` is from Windows.h(winuser.h).

Comment: You are going to need to add error checking. Once you do that you can report to us which API call fails. It's also not clear that the text is null-terminated. Are you sure that it is?

Comment: I am using .NET language to add it in there, and I am using UpdateResourceW API to add it there, I don't know if it's nullterminated. Can you show me an example code how you would read the data from RCData to char* - without knowing if it is nullterminated or not... ?

Comment: Call `SizeofResource` to get the size of the text. I won't help you until you add some error checking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LoadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPI like this:

```
HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
char myString[512];
LoadString(hMod, IDS_STRING101, myString, 512);
MessageBox(NULL, myString, "", MB_OK);
```

IDS_STRING101 has been defined in your .rc file

Comment: Thank you but this does not answer my question. I am trying to load string from the resource which can be seen in the image I linked; which is RCData directory.